# Number of Parameters in a Multinomial Logistic Model (Varying Sample Sizes Across Dependent Variable Groups)

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, model, multinomial-distribution, multinomial-logit

I have a dependent variable which consists of an unordered set of 12 groups (1, 2, 3 ... 12). I'd like to fit a multinomial logistic model, with group 1 as the reference class (essentially a series of single logistic models of group 1, 2 ... 11 vs group 1). However, the groups have very different sample sizes (smallest is 21, largest is around 600). My dilemma is in how to specify the model given these difference in sample size.

Issue 1: If I take the smallest group into consideration it would seem as if I should only include ~2 predictor variables, however, I have more room to work with when considering the larger groups.

Issue 2: Furthermore, given the small sizes of the smaller groups, there is potential for perfect classification and unstable parameter estimates for some of the variables -- this begs the question of whether I should remove these variables from the entire model, or just from the model when analyzing the smaller groups.

Does anyone have any experience in similar cases? Thank you in advance for your help!